# Minifilter - not getting IRP_MJ_CREATE requests

Tags: registration, minifilter

I'm developing a minifilter driver based on the minispy example and I'm having trouble to understand why my filter is getting called a few hundred times per second when it should only catch IRP_MJ_CREATE and nothing is created at that time.

I didn't found much help in the web or I've searched for the wrong thing or made a mistake on a different part...

so here is how I'm registering my Pre and Post Operations:

```
CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
    { IRP_MJ_CREATE,
      0,
      logfilterPreOperation,
      logfilterPostOperation },
    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};
```

and here the filter itself...

```
CONST FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {

    sizeof( FLT_REGISTRATION ),         //  Size
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,           //  Version
    0,                                  //  Flags
    Contexts,                           //  Context
    Callbacks,                          //  Operation callbacks
    logfilterUnload,                    //  MiniFilterUnload
    NULL,                               //  InstanceSetup
    logfilterInstanceQueryTeardown,     //  InstanceQueryTeardown
    NULL,                               //  InstanceTeardownStart
    NULL,                               //  InstanceTeardownComplete
    NULL,                               //  GenerateFileName
    NULL,                               //  GenerateDestinationFileName
    NULL                                //  NormalizeNameComponent
};
```

register and start...
    Context.DriverObject = DriverObject;

```
// register filter
DEB_PRINT("DriverEntry: register filter... \n");
status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject,&FilterRegistration,&Context.FltFilter);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    DEB_PRINT("DriverEntry: registration failed. status=%#08x \n",status);
    return status;
}

// start data server
InitServer();

// start filtering
DEB_PRINT("DriverEntry: start filtering... \n");
status = FltStartFiltering(Context.FltFilter);
if (!NT_SUCCESS( status )) {
    DEB_PRINT("DriverEntry: start filtering failed. status=%#08x \n",status);
    FltUnregisterFilter(Context.FltFilter);
    return status;
}
```

this all is pretty similar to the minispy example.

So why am I getting all these "senseless" calls or what did I unterstand wrong?

Any help would be great.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the confusing world of windows device drivers specially file system filter.
You are the not only one who is accessing the resources but in os there are some other 
Processes and they can send you a lot of create's. for example : Explorer.exe etc.
So no need to worry about it.if you will say no to automatic attachment to the volumes then 
you won Half the battle. hope this may help.

Comment: hi, I'm suppressing automatic attachments already .. `Instance1.Flags         = 0x1              ; Supress automatic attachments` and should i not still get a filename? for example the explorer has to write to somewhere. even if it is some cryptic name, i thought there should be at least something.. but i'm gonna keep on tryin. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome automatic attachment in your InstanceSetUp callback using this

```
if ( FlagOn( Flags, FLTFL_INSTANCE_SETUP_AUTOMATIC_ATTACHMENT ) ) 
{

    return STATUS_FLT_DO_NOT_ATTACH;
}
```

then you can try to attach on demand using `FltAttachVolume()` or `FltAttachAtAltitude()` etc msdn
search. It'll definitly resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Richmont, Just to add some more information,

IRP_MJ_CREATE is not only for creating a new file / folder but for opening any file / folder for reading or execution, "IRP_MJ_CREATE" is also called.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff548630(v=vs.85).aspx

"The I/O Manager sends the IRP_MJ_CREATE request when a new file or directory is being created, or when an existing file, device, directory, or volume is being opened"

Comment: hi, my problem was no problem at all. It works correct the way I implemented it.  I was not using the debugger at this time, but I was using an Client connectet to the Minifilter to show me all the captured data. My mistake was that have been copied data that was as long as the pointer to the data and not the actual data.

Comment: thanks I was wondering why it was getting called many times for the same file

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you setup the instance setup callback parameters. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nc-fltkernel-pflt_instance_setup_callback).
Notice the **FLTFL_INSTANCE_SETUP_MANUAL_ATTACHMENT** flag. Don't set that if you want to automatically attach to all volumes.
In fact notice all the flags and read about each one and decide what you want.

Your filter is called hunders of times and more because behind the scenes the OS is working, alongside with other processes and driver which all have to do their work, and that work usually involves working with files. To get an idea of how that world is check out [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) form SysInternals.

Good luck.